Display data from a Cursor in a LazyColumn
I'm converting an android app to Jetpack Compose and would like to convert a RecyclerView that displays hundreds of thousands of rows into a LazyColumn. I used a RecyclerView.Adapter for the RecyclerView and was able to read through a database cursor at any given position. What is the best practice in Jetpack Compose for displaying data in a LazyColumn from a Cursor (e.g. via a Flow in a ViewModel)?
I've tried the following in a ViewModel but it will put the entire result set into a list, and I'd like to avoid keeping it all in memory.
private fun updateOrgList() {
        val filter = _orgFilter.value
        val cursor = pkmAndroid.queryOrgList(filter)
        repeat(cursor.count) {
            // todo do this in a better way!
            cursor.moveToPosition(it)
            val org = PkmAndroid.getOrganisationFromCursor(cursor);
            _orgList.value += org
        }
    }

